# What is the help file format

Tags: android, file-format

ALL,

We are trying to rewrite a huge software that is written in wxWidgets + Qt to run on Android tablet and we are trying to rewrite it in JAVA (as it is a natural language for development in Android). Our old system is using RoboHelp to generate Help files and then the RoboHelp libraries are put on the Client system for the Search functionality.

One of the pieces that needs to be redefined is a Help system (and also a Context-Sensitive Help).

I just tried to search for which file format (html, xml, etc) can be used to implement file formats. However, Google give me a bunch of links for video/audio and all other stuff but nothing is related to Help system. I believe it is because Help in Android applications is not really defined and there is not to many applications written for Android that requires Help system.

Does anybody here have an idea? Google Material Design does not say anything in this regards - they just tell you that there should be a Help button with a possible drawer implementation and that about it. But there is nothing about Help content file format.

The Help system should support navigation and search capabilities.

Thank you for any suggestions you can provide

Comment: Android doesn't have a built-in help system, so there is no format

Comment: @SLaks, that's exactly what I was afraid of. ;-) thank you for confirming. I guess we will need to come up with something.